# writing a script to update the records of a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a  table in my db that is oracle db i am using and the table name is AAA table

below is the structure ..

```
CREATE TABLE AAA (
  id              NUMBER(32,0)  NOT NULL,
  tk_id         VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  abc_system   VARCHAR2(20)  
  ument_code VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL,

)
    )
```

now i am using the below query to update a single row

```
UPDATE  AAA SET  tk_id = '2768_ADS ADLT' , SET  abc_system = 'NULL'  WHERE  id=1
```

now as shown above basically i have to merge the value of two columns into one column that
before this update the values of individual columns was

```
  tk_id     abc_system 
   12         FGTR
```

After the above update the values are ..

```
  tk-id     abc_system
  12FGTR     NULL
```

now the issue is that there are 60 recordrs in the table and i want to merge the value for both the columns into one column finally that is under tk_id

please advise the sql script to achieve this..

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE AAA
SET TK_ID = TK_ID || ABC_SYSTEM,
        ABC_SYSTEM = NULL
WHERE ABC_SYSTEM IS NOT NULL;
```